# Fail when using the taint tracking submodule of CodeQl

Tags: java, codeql

Firstly, this is my ql script

```
/**
 * @id java/taint
 * @name taint
 * @description taint
 * @kind path-problem
 * @problem.severity warning
 */

import java
import semmle.code.java.dataflow.DataFlow
import semmle.code.java.dataflow.FlowSources
import semmle.code.java.dataflow.TaintTracking
import DataFlow::PathGraph

private class Sink extends DataFlow::Node {
  Sink() { exists(MethodAccess c | c.getMethod().hasName("wxLogin") and c = this.asExpr()) }
}

private class Source extends DataFlow::Node {
  Source() {
    exists(Parameter p |
      p = this.asParameter() and
      exists(Annotation a |
        a = p.getAnAnnotation() and
        a.getType().getName() = "RequestParam"
      )
    )
  }
}

class Configuration extends TaintTracking::Configuration {
  Configuration() { this = "Configuration" }

  override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node source) { source instanceof RemoteFlowSource }

  override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) { sink instanceof Sink }
}

from Configuration cfg, DataFlow::PathNode source, DataFlow::PathNode sink
where cfg.hasFlowPath(source, sink)
select source.getNode(), source, sink, "source"
/*
 * from Sink s
 * select s
 */

/*
 * from RemoteFlowSource r
 * select r
 */
```

And the project I use to build the database is from
[github](https://github.com/fu123dawe/weixin-java-miniapp-demo-master)

A key part of the source project is

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public void getCode(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
        List<WxMaProperties.Config> configs = wxMaProperties.getConfigs();
        String s = userService.wxLogin(configs.get(0).getAppid(), code);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

which is expected to be found a datapath in.

The taint spreads from `String code` to `wxLogin()`.

But the CodeQl gives no output.

I wonder if I should do extra configs when analyzing a spring project?

I've already tried to select the sources and the sinks, which turn out to work well enough

[sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIxsv.png)

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRCxd.png)

Comment: The problem might be `c = this.asExpr()` for your `Sink`. The sink should probably not be the method call as a whole, but an argument to the method call. Could you please try replacing `c = this.asExpr()` with `c.getAnArgument() = this.asExpr()` and see if that works?